# Find basis of 4x3 Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been confused with the following matrix. I'm trying to find the basis of the image of A:

$$A= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
6&4&10\\
4&-1&3\\
-2&-5&-7\\
-10&-3&-13 \end{array}\right)$$

Normally for these types of problems I'm used to row reducing and not having any issues, however for this problem since it is a 4x3 matrix I'm honestly not sure what to do. I got my matrix to be reduced to the following:

$$A= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&1\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0 \end{array}\right)$$

I thought the answer was going to be the following however it is incorrect:

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1\\
-1\\
1\\
0\end{array}\right)$$

What am I doing wrong? I figure its something simple to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Let denote by $c_i$ the $i$-th column of $A$. Notice that $c_3=c_1+c_2$ and that $c_1$ and $c_2$ are not colinear so they are linearly independent so $(c_1,c_2)$ is a basis for the image of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

The vector you gave is a basis for the kernel (or nullspace) of $A$, not the image (or column space) of $A$.

Hints: The image of $A$ (or more properly the image of the linear transformation $x \mapsto Ax$) is the column space of $A$.

In the Gaussian elimination algorithm, the columns of the original matrix $A$ that have pivots in them are a basis for the column space of $A$.

Also, you should not write that $A =$ the reduced row echelon form.  The matrix $A$ is the one given in the problem; the reduced row echelon form matrix is a different matrix (many people call it $R$) that is obtained from the Gaussian elimination algorithm.